# OpenVPN Client - DNS change; role of 4 FreeVPN.me profiles; How to remove DNS leak

Tags: vpn, dns, openvpn, bittorrent, opendns

I have configured OpenVPN client added and FreeVPN,me bundle. Tested all seems works fine.
However I have few quires

1. How do I know VPN works fine and connection is secured other than OpenVPN green colour icon?
2. There are 4 profiles – TCP443, TCP80, UDP4000, UDP53; what is the different between them?; why we need 4 profiles?
3. My home router is configured to use OpenDNS to protect kids from accessing certain contents this includes torrent sites however when I am using VPN I need to access them; therefore how to configure client env to use different DNS or configure to use default DNS of the FreeVPN.me ?
4. If question two doesn’t answer this; how do I make sure bit torrent will use VPN connection?
5. FreeVPN,me; does it full tunnel or partial tunnel; if partial tunnel what does it mean to non tech person.
6. Considering above setup at my house; is there any room for DNS leak? If yes how to fix it.

Note: Lot of words and stuff I grab from reading loads of forums; therefore my apology if I misunderstood them.

Fernando

Answer (score 1):

1. How do I know if my VPN connection is secured other than the OpenVPN green colour icon?

**A**: You don't unless you check http://ipleak.net/

2. There are 4 profiles – TCP443, TCP80, UDP4000, UDP53; what is the
   different between them?; why we need 4 profiles?

**A**: They are all individual configuration files.
The main difference is whether you want a TCP or UDP connection. UDP is faster (it wraps tcp in udp), TCP is more compatible (but more overhead). Port 443 could be used if port 80 is blocked. The same for port 4000 if udp53 would be blocked.

3. My home router is configured to use OpenDNS to protect kids from
   accessing certain contents this includes torrent sites however when
   I am using VPN I need to access them; therefore how to configure
   client env to use different DNS or configure to use default DNS of
   the FreeVPN.me ?

**A: Would the VPN alone not change your DNS you can include the following ==>**

Install firefox and disable WebRTC detection.
Install Foxyproxy for firefox
Gather socks proxy info from the internet and configure foxyproxy
++ I use 'xroxy (dot) com' to filter and find ‘socks proxies’, and use www.sockslist.net to check if the proxy works. 
This way you should have your DNS changed, and an extra security layer.
You can set up Vuze to only accept data from the VPN adapter (ip binding), and set it up to use the socks proxy too. This way you can ensure that Vuze isn’t using the DNS from the router.
If the VPN dies, Vuze won’t be able to download.

I always pick Russian proxies as they are near to the VPN server (Romania), and it’s pretty fast.

4. FreeVPN,me; does it full tunnel or partial tunnel; if partial tunnel what does it mean to non tech person.
   +
   Considering above setup at my house; is there any room for DNS leak? If yes how to fix it.

**A**: From my experience I can’t get it to work without it leaking my DNS. When I force windows  to use the VPN-DNS I can’t seem to connect to websites.
The solution would be as suggested above: use a socks proxy combined with VPN. I have had 0 DNS leaks since.\

**Extra info regarding Vuze:**

**+ Disable the following options**

- utp
- upnp

**+ Do NOT use the Mainline DHT (or other) plugin(s).**

If enabled Vuze might bypass the socks proxy. That would reveal your vpn ip, if you're connected to one, and your ISP might know you’re downloading torrents if they use a transparent proxy to track you.

Also make sure to disable IPv6 on all network adapters, according to different forums disabling IPv6 helps with guarding your privacy when downloading torrents.

I hope that these are the answers you were looking for.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found a new solution to prevent DNS leaking!
This doesn't involve relying on socks proxies.

However, I still advise firefox to disable WebRTC detection.

- Go to http://download.dnscrypt.org/dnscrypt-proxy/
- Extract the "dnscrypt-proxy-win32" folder to C:\
- Then download the zip file containing "DNSCrypt Windows Service
  Manager 0.2" Download it from here:
  https://simonclausen.dk/projects/dnscrypt-winservicemgr/
- Extract dnscrypt-winservicemgr.exe from the zip-file and put it in "C:\dnscrypt-proxy-win32\bin"
- run the "dnscrypt-winservicemgr.exe" file with admin rights. I made all hidden adapters visible, selected all adapters, and enabled the DNSCrypt protection. It should show green and say enabled. (Once this is set-up you can leave close it for automatic configuration the next time you start up your pc, or you can disable it).

After this, I started the freevpn.me OpenVPN connection, and noticed that it was still leaking DNS, so I changed the DNS connection of my 1st internet adapter to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 (I connect over WiFi, for others this might be LAN).

After checking all my adapters, the TAP adapter had it's dns set to 127.0.0.1 (done by the DNSCrypt service).

The overall combination of DNSCrypt and the google DNS for my 1st internet finally relieved me from the transparent proxy headaches with my provider.

Answer (score -2):

All you have to do is go to your openvpn client select free VPN. Me and the server that you're going to right click it and then go to configure when you open the config file it should be a text file, add the following line to the very end of the code

```
Block-outside-dns
```

then go up to the top and save the file close everything out and reopen. That will get rid of the DNS leak